# Spark MLLib Crossvalidation of SVM

Tags: apache-spark, svm, cross-validation, apache-spark-mllib

I use Spark MLLib to conduct a SVM classification on a RDD of LabeledPoints. 
I want to cross validate it. Which is the best way to do it?
Does anyone have an example code? I found the CrossValidator class which relies on a DataFrame though.

My aim is to obtain the F-score.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue for over a month until I realized that I must use the ML API instead of the MLlib API (more about the differences between both of them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835829/whats-the-difference-between-spark-ml-and-mllib-packages)). In that case, the SVM for the new API is the [LinearSVC](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/LinearSVC.html):

```py
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier, LinearSVC
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder, CrossValidatorModel
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

# SVM
crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=LinearSVC(),
                          estimatorParamMaps=ParamGridBuilder().build(),
                          evaluator=MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName='f1'),
                          numFolds=5,
                          parallelism=4)

# Random Forest
crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=RandomForestClassifier(),
                          estimatorParamMaps=ParamGridBuilder().build(),
                          evaluator=MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName='f1'),
                          numFolds=5,
                          parallelism=4)
```

In both cases you can just fit the model:

```py
cross_model: CrossValidatorModel = crossval.fit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a complete example [on Spark's github](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/CrossValidatorExample.scala), though not with SVM but logistic regression.

The best way is to change your RDD into a DataFrame using `rdd.toDF()` method.

Comment: Thanks so far. In the example a LogisticRegression object is instanciated and inserted into the pipeline. It can't find any SVM to instantiate which fits into the pipeline though. Which class to use?