# type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I am new to scala and mllib and I have been getting the following error. Please let me know if anyone has been able to resolve something similar.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.{KMeans, KMeansModel}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
.
.
.
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("SampleApp")
val sContext = new SparkContext(conf)
val sc = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("SampleApp").getOrCreate()
val sampleData = sc.read.json("input/sampleData.json")
val clusters = KMeans.train(sampleData, 10, 10)
val WSSSE = clusters.computeCost(sampleData)
clusters.save(sc, "target/org/apache/spark/KMeansExample/KMeansModel")
val sameModel = KMeansModel.load(sContext, "target/org/apache/spark/KMeansExample/KMeansModel")
```

this above line gives an error as:

```
type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame (which expands to) org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]
```

So I tried:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans
val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(20)
val model = kmeans.fit(sampleData)
val predictions = model.transform(sampleData)
val evaluator = new ClusteringEvaluator()
val silhouette = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
```

This gives the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "features" does not exist.
Available fields: address, attributes, business_id
at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:267)
at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:267)
at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.apply(StructType.scala:266)
at org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnTypes(SchemaUtils.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.validateVectorCompatibleColumn(SchemaUtils.scala:119)
at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeansParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(KMeans.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans.validateAndTransformSchema(KMeans.scala:285)
at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans.transformSchema(KMeans.scala:382)
at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans$$anonfun$fit$1.apply(KMeans.scala:341)
at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans$$anonfun$fit$1.apply(KMeans.scala:340)
at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$$anonfun$11.apply(Instrumentation.scala:183)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.instrumented(Instrumentation.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans.fit(KMeans.scala:340)
```

I have been referring to https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html and https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html

**Edit**

Using setFeaturesCol()

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("is_open", "review_count", "stars"))
  .setOutputCol("features")
val output = assembler.transform(sampleData).select("features")
val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(20).setFeaturesCol("features")
val model = kmeans.fit(output)
val predictions = model.transform(sampleData)
val evaluator = new ClusteringEvaluator()
val silhouette = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
println(s"Silhouette with squared euclidean distance = $silhouette")
```

This gives a different error still:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getSimpleName(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;
at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation.logPipelineStage(Instrumentation.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans$$anonfun$fit$1.apply(KMeans.scala:350)
at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans$$anonfun$fit$1.apply(KMeans.scala:340)
at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$$anonfun$11.apply(Instrumentation.scala:183)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.instrumented(Instrumentation.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans.fit(KMeans.scala:340)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please read [What's the difference between Spark ML and MLLIB packages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38835829/10465355) and choose one or another, with appropriate distributed data structures.

Comment: Use the newer ml library (as in your second try). For `KMeans` you need to specify which column to use as input (the default is "features", hence the error that features does not exist). Use `setFeaturesCol()` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the scala pipeline

```
val assembler = new VectorAssembler() 
                    .setInputCols(Array("feature1",feature2","feature3")) 
                    .setOutputCol("assembled_features")
 val scaler = new StandardScaler() 
      .setInputCol("assembled_features") 
      .setOutputCol("features") 
      .setWithStd(true) 
      .setWithMean(false)
    
 val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1L)
    // create the pipeline
    val pipeline = new Pipeline() 
      .setStages(Array(assembler, scaler, kmeans))
    
    // Fit the model 
    val clussterModel = pipeline.fit(train)
```